# Problem understanding serializer.data structure

Tags: django, serialization, deserialization

I need some help from someone with better knowledge than myself, to understand this.

I have a queryset of data and some context data that I send into a rather complex ModelSerializer. The Modelserializer adds (using the context data) fields to the data that doesn't come from the model itself.

When I then look at serializer.data it looks like

[OrderedDict([('field1', value1), ('field2', value2),....]),OrderedDict([('field1', value1), ('field2', value2),....])]

when I drill down into next level

```
for item in serializer.data:
   print(item)

   Output: OrderedDict([('field1', value1), ('field2', value2),....])
```

how can I access value1, value2 ?

if I iterate in next level it only generates the key values,'field1','field2' etc

```
for i in item:
    print(i)

    Output: 'field1'
```

I understand there might be much better functions. But I'm doing it this very simple way to try to understand the structure of the data (without success aparantly).

I hope someone understands my question and is able to explain to me.

I've been playing around with deserialisation but I suspect the structure of the modelserializer doesn't allow it to be used. Is it correct that deserialisation only work on datasets that are 100% generated from the model in the Modelserializer in question?

Comment: It's deserilized data means data you have is python object. Here you are getting the list of dictionaries so if you just want the value of each column then iterate  `item` dictionary with 'item.values()` and want both then 'item.items()` like we do with python dictionary.

if your serialized data includes additional fields introduced by the ModelSerializer through the context, deserialization might require custom handling to ignore or process those additional fields appropriately.

Comment: A good night sleep and a simple explanation is sometimes everything that is needed. Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 0):

consider [OrderedDict([('field1', value1), ('field2', value2),....]),OrderedDict([('field1', value1), ('field2', value2),....])] as a list of Users (or any other Model). then each OrderedDict is a User model and contains fields and values like username, email, etc. now you can acess each item fields and values like below:

```
for item in serializer.data:
    # access to all fields and values for each item
    for field, value in item.items():
        print(f'{field}: {value}')
```

consider ModelSerializer must be capable of desrializing data that conforms to the expected format.